# Simple C - Extracting instant value of a variable and storing it

Tags: c

Disclaimer: I’ve never used C before a few weeks ago, and I’m somewhat new to programming in general.

I’m writing a really basic space invaders type game in C. We have a little motherboard with a screen, joystick and buttons to port it to. I’m far from done but how it currently works is this:

-the character can move around the bottom of the screen from left to right with the joystick

-when the button is pressed, it creates a bullet right above his head that moves up to the top then vanishes

Now here’s where there’s a problem. In order to make the bullet spawn right above his head, I had to use the x coordinate of the character to define where to create the bullet. These are stored in variables, which are modified in the joystick code whenever the joystick is moved.

The movement of the bullet occurs like this: a black square quickly covers up the bullet, and a new bullet is drawn just above it. This repeats until the bullet hits the top.

So, the problem is that the bullet moves about the x-axis just like the character does. This is because all the rectangles for the bullet’s “movement” are defined such that their x coordinate is the variable of the Character’s x coordinate, which of course changes with the joystick.

so my question is this: is it possible in C to extract the INSTANT, integer value of a variable? For example, if I can nab the instant value of the character’s x-coordinate when the first rectangle of the bullet is created, then re-use that unchanging integer (as another variable) for the x-coordinate for subsequent rectangles, it will appear as if the movement of the bullet is straight up, despite the character still moving about.

TLDR: Is it possible in C to extract the instant integer value of an often-changing variable and store it in another variable for temporary use?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Yes possible. Show what you have done

Comment: yes just create a new variable and write the content of the old one into it. `int old = 5; int new = old;`

Comment: you mean is possible in C to copy a integer ? Yes, I think it's possible ;) You should create an structure that represent your bullet and just put it a x and y integer. If you want a better answer you should add a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like you're asking for the assignment operator. It's `=` in C ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. Put the assignment in a code block that will only be executed when the button is pressed. This way the bullets x position won't be updated until you shoot again.